# Change script to paste values only and name final copy file to cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a script that, when triggered, will save a record of reports I send to my boss. I have located a script that almost does what I need. I want to copy one sheet in a spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet (without copying any container-bound scripts) as values only, and rename the new spreadsheet file to a cell value from the original sheet.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
//******************************************************************************
//- This function takes a tab and makes it its own file
function tabToSheet(gDrive,tabName,fileName,destination){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gDrive);
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName(tabName);

  //create a new document in the location given
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("TEMPDELETEME");

  //copy the tab from current document to new document 
  ss.copyTo(newSheet);
  var id = newSheet.getId();

  newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
  os = newSheet.getSheets()[0];
  os.setName(tabName);

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination);


  var finalId = file.makeCopy(fileName, folder).getId();
  file.setTrashed(true);

  return finalId;

}//*****************************************************************************
```

I have two questions:

1.) This script copies values and formulas. How can I change the script to paste values only? When I look at the reference documentation, I think that I can add the "{contentsOnly:true});" tag to a copyTo statement. (But I'm no expert, I don't consider myself a developer, and contrary to appearances, don't have a good understanding of what I'm doing...) So, what I'm asking is this - which statement? where? or is there another way to do this?

2.) I need to rename the final spreadsheet to a string value in a cell in the original sheet. How can I do this?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

<s>1. To copy just the values, you could change</s>

`ss.copyTo(newSheet);`

to

`ss.copyTo(newSheet, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES)`

[Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

2. To rename the final spreadsheet to a string value in a cell in the original sheet, you need to:

I. Get the name from the original sheet using a line like this:

`var newFileName = ss.getRange("B7").getValue(); // if the name is in B7`

II. Set the name of the new file to this value by changing

`os.setName(tabName);`

to

`os.setName(newFileName);`

---

### Edit

Tanaike-san is correct. Please try this instead to copy just the displayed values and paste them in a new tab:

```
function tabToSheet(gDrive, tabName, fileName, destination){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gDrive);
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName(tabName);

  // Get values to be copied and the name of the new tab to be created.
  var valuesOnly = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var newFileName = ss.getRange("B7").getValue(); // if the name is in B7

  // Create a new document in the location given
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("TEMPDELETEME");
  var newTab = newSheet.getSheets()[0];

  // Post values and rename tab
  newTab.getRange(1, 1, valuesOnly.length, valuesOnly[0].length).setValues(valuesOnly);
  newTab.setName(newFileName);

  var id = newSheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination);  
  var finalId = file.makeCopy(fileName, folder).getId();
  file.setTrashed(true);
  return finalId;
}
```

---

The creation of a temporary copy and deleting it is not strictly necessary. It may be more efficient to do this:

```
function tabToSheet(gDrive, tabName, fileName, destination){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gDrive);
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName(tabName);

  // Get values to be copied and the name of the new tab to be created.
  var valuesOnly = ss.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var newFileName = ss.getRange("B7").getValue(); // if the name is in B7

  //create a new document in the location given
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
  var newTab = newSheet.getSheets()[0];

  // Post values and tab name
  newTab.getRange(1, 1, valuesOnly.length, valuesOnly[0].length).setValues(valuesOnly);
  newTab.setName(newFileName);

  var id = newSheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination).addFile(file);
  DriveApp.removeFile(file); // to remove it from the root folder
  return id;
}
```

Comment: In OP's script, I think that `copyTo` of `ss.copyTo(newSheet)` is `copyTo` of Class Sheet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

Comment: ADW - I'm getting an error on the line: "ss.copyTo(newSheet, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);" (This was "ss.copyTo(newSheet);" but was changed.). The error text is: "Cannot find method copyTo((class)(class)google.apps.maestro.server.beans.trix.api.CopyPasteType). (line 19, file "Code")" Where do I go from here?

Comment: All, thank you so much for all of your help! (I can only dream of the day when I'm as smart as all of you...) Both of the scripts offered in the reply worked great! However, I did notice that everything is copying as values, as I had asked. Can I impose again asking for an edit? Is there a way to paste the format, too?